# spark submit with phoenix

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, apache-phoenix

I'm Trying to connect to phoenix using spark submit on secured cluster I have this Exception

> ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: Trying to connect to a secure cluster
>   with keytab:/hbase-secure 17/06/29 11:54:44 ERROR Executor: Exception
>   in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103
>   (08004): Unable to establish connection.

On my program I want to save to phoenix a dataframe (the program part that generate the exception) I already compiled and saved to phoenix from my intelliji but it's not working from spark submit even with master local

this is the part of code that generate the exception

```
       df.write
        .format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
        .mode("overwrite")
        .option("table", output)
        .option("zkUrl", "sv005689.info.ratp:2181") 
        .save()
```

this my spark submit command

```
spark-submit --class TEST.PHOENIX --master local --executor-memory 10G --num-executors 50 --conf spark.ui.port=14040  spark-assembly-0.0.2.jar
```

this is my exception

```
17/06/29 11:54:43 INFO ConnectionQueryServicesImpl: Trying to connect to a secure cluster with keytab:/hbase-secure
17/06/29 11:54:44 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 103 (08004): Unable to establish connection.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:422)
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:145)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:392)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.access$300(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:211)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2269)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2248)
        at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:78)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2248)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:233)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:135)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:98)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:82)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.ConnectionUtil.getOutputConnection(ConnectionUtil.java:70)
        at org.apache.phoenix.mapreduce.util.PhoenixConfigurationUtil.getUpsertColumnMetadataList(PhoenixConfigurationUtil.java:230)
        at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:45)
        at org.apache.phoenix.spark.DataFrameFunctions$$anonfun$2.apply(DataFrameFunctions.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$22.apply(RDD.scala:717)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:313)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:277)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Login failure for 2181 from keytab /hbase-secure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytab(UserGroupInformation.java:987)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.login(SecurityUtil.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User$SecureHadoopUser.login(User.java:386)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.User.login(User.java:253)
        at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.openConnection(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:380)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Unable to obtain password from user

        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.promptForPass(Krb5LoginModule.java:897)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.attemptAuthentication(Krb5LoginModule.java:760)
        at com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule.login(Krb5LoginModule.java:617)
```

Can someone help me to resolve this issue
 thank you for your help

Comment: maybe you have to kinit first?

Comment: thank you,I already test it but I still have the same error

Comment: @Noraettata do you know what sbt dependency you used?